# Issue with aspose.cell ”.HtmlString” property ,When html tag text contain character “&”

Tags: aspose-cells

**HTML**

```
<Font Style='FONT-FAMILY: Arial;FONT-SIZE: 9pt;COLOR: #000000;TEXT-ALIGN: left;FONT-WEIGHT: bold;'>Status: </Font>
<Font Style='FONT-FAMILY: Arial;FONT-SIZE: 9pt;COLOR: #000000;TEXT-ALIGN: left;'>REGISTERED 8 **&** 15, June 20, 2003</Font>
<Font Style='FONT-FAMILY: Arial;FONT-SIZE: 9pt;COLOR: #000000;TEXT-ALIGN: left;FONT-WEIGHT: bold;'>Int'l Class: </Font>
<Font Style='FONT-FAMILY: Arial;FONT-SIZE: 9pt;COLOR: #000000;TEXT-ALIGN: left;'> 25</Font>
```

Processed HTML by `aspose` property `.HtmlString`

```
**worksheet.Cells[rowTiled, columnTiled].HtmlString = __htmlString;**

<Font Style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold;FONT-FAMILY: Arial;FONT-SIZE: 9pt;COLOR: #000000;">Status: </Font>
<Font Style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial;FONT-SIZE: 9pt;COLOR: #000000;">REGISTERED 8 **&amp;** 15, June 20, 2003&lt;/Font&gt;
&lt;Font Style='FONT-FAMILY: Arial;FONT-SIZE: 9pt;COLOR: #000000;TEXT-ALIGN: left;FONT-WEIGHT: bold;'&gt;Int'l Class: </Font>
<Font Style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial;FONT-SIZE: 9pt;COLOR: #000000;"> 25</Font>
```

Issue with `aspose` `.HtmlString` property process character `&` to `&amp;` but it also convert some html tag `< and>` in encoded format. 
This formation create wrong string, that’s why I got HTML text in my Excel Sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working as Social Media Developer at Aspose.

Well, you need to use "&amp ;" instead of "&" in your html string to use it with Aspose.Cells for .NET. I checked the following code with [latest version](http://goo.gl/fYpvgu) and it works fine.

```
//instantiate workbook
Workbook wb = new Workbook();

//Get worksheet
Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[0];

//Get Cells
Aspose.Cells.Cells cell = ws.Cells;

//Set HTML String
cell[0, 0].HtmlString = "<Font Style='FONT-FAMILY: Arial;FONT-SIZE: 9pt;COLOR: #000000;TEXT-ALIGN: left;FONT-WEIGHT: bold;'>Status: </Font><Font Style='FONT-FAMILY: Arial;FONT-SIZE: 9pt;COLOR: #000000;TEXT-ALIGN: left;'>REGISTERED 8 &amp; 15, June 20, 2003</Font><Font Style='FONT-FAMILY: Arial;FONT-SIZE: 9pt;COLOR: #000000;TEXT-ALIGN: left;FONT-WEIGHT: bold;'>Int'l Class: </Font><Font Style='FONT-FAMILY: Arial;FONT-SIZE: 9pt;COLOR: #000000;TEXT-ALIGN: left;'> 25</Font>";

//Save Workbook
wb.Save("c:\\data\\outputhtmlstring.xlsx");
```

Comment: Thanks,i try same in my solution but some how it's not working ,but little bit change in my code for encoding string and issue resolved.